# Stylus css within Slim template with Sinatra

Tags: css, sinatra, stylus, slim-lang

I'm using Sinatra, and I'm trying to use Slim for the HTML and Stylus for the the CSS.

I'm unsure of what the correct way to do this is. What I've got at the moment works (locally, I've not tried deploying), but I'm wondering if this is the most efficient way of doing things.

My **layout.slim** file has:

```
styl:
   @import('style')
```

.. in the **head**. Is this the best way using Stylus stylesheets, or should I set up a /style path in the sinatra app.rb?

My code is below:

---

This is my **app.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'       # ruby url route patterns framework
require 'slim'          # html templating
require 'stylus'        # css templating
require 'stylus/tilt'

get '/' do
  @page_title = "Home"
  slim :index
end
```

---

In the views folder, I have a **layout.slim** which looks like this

```
html
  head
    title #{@page_title}

    styl:
      @import('style')

  body
    #header header in layout.slim

    #central-area
      == yield

    #footer
```

---

An **index.slim** which looks like this

```
p this is the index which is 'yielded' in the layout.slim
```

---

In the same folder as **app.rb**, I have **style.styl**:

```
color-combo1()
  color white
  background-color red
color-combo2()
  color #eeeeee
  background-color blue
#header
  color-combo1()
  padding 5px
  width 100%
#central-area
  padding 0px 20px
  color #111111
#footer
  color-combo2()
  padding 5px
```

Comment: I'd set up a route for it, then you gain some encapsulation as it appears the same as any external style sheet would, allowing you to swap Stylus for something else later, or pre-processed CSS. That's just my opinion, if what you have works then it works.

Comment: That's not forgetting the obvious external stylesheet vs CSS in the header argument, which was won years ago by external stylesheets.

Comment: did you get the styl: to work..I am getting a compile error